# Setting Up a Personal VPN with OpenVPN

Tags: 18.04, server

I found the following link for setting up a personal VPN: https://averagelinuxuser.com/linux-vpn-server/

However, they talk about a 'private server' and I am wondering: 
What is it, how does one obtain it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A private server is a server only you access. You can have it at your home or workplace, it can be a dedicated machine locked up someplace else which only you connect to, or it can be a 'virtual' machine, a slice of a PC which someone maintains for you, but only you access that 'slice'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Concretely, I have a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Should I now download VirtualBox in order to set up a private server?

Comment: That's another question. Ground rules here have us limiting the scope of each question so that we end up with a Q&A database with useful atomicity. Therefore, please make that its own question. If this answer was useful, please click the up-arrowhead; if it solved the problem for you, please -also- click the checkmark. Both are to the left of the beginning of the answer.